# Defining a function as variable

Tags: r, function

I want to make a function with R that uses pre-integrated functions to give me the area under the curve. For example, the integral of the function x^2 from 1 to 2.

This is what i have so far:

```
my.integrate <- function(x1, y, z) {
  Gl2 <- replace(x1, x, y)
  Gl1 <- replace(x1, x, z)
  anzac <- Gl2[1] - Gl2[1]

  return(anzac)
}
```

I want x1 to be x^2 (or any function of x) then later have x be defined as my y and z values anyone know of a way how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a `function(x)` as argument and use it in your `my.integrate`-wrapper.

```
> my.integrate <- function(f, y, z) {
+   f(z) - f(y)
+ }
> my.integrate(function(x) x, 1, 2)
[1] 1
> my.integrate(function(x) x^2, 1, 2)
[1] 3
> my.integrate(function(x) x^3, 1, 2)
[1] 7
```